# How can I check if a list of patterns is not there in my list of filenames?

Tags: python, regex

Want to discard a set of files with specific fileformats. Example, those listed in the patterns list.

```
     patterns =[r'\.pdf$',r'\.mpeg$'] 
     NOT_FILE = [ re.compile(p) for p in patterns] 
     grep_not_match = (lambda l, regex: [each for each in l if (regex.search(e)))])

     for rt,dr,files in os.walk(rootdirectory):
         files = grep_not_match(files,NOT_FILE)
```

I know, I'm making a super stupid mistake here, Can anyone figure out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for a simple task like this. You can just use endswith:

```
files = [f for f in files if not f.endswith(('.pdf', '.mpeg'))]
```

Comment: Damn.. Why didn't I think o that. :( Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension looks like it should read:    [each for each in l if (regex.search(each)))])

Seems like this is at least part of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) module for this purpose.

```
fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.pdf'):
```

> Test whether the filename string matches the pattern string, returning
>   True or False